# Using ranges in Matlab/Octave matrices

Tags: matlab, math, vector, matrix, octave

Let's say I want to create an 100x100 matrix of which every row
contains the elements 1-100

```
A = [1:100; 1:100; 1:100... n]
```

Obviously forming a matrix is a bad idea, because it would force me to
create 100 rows of range 1:100.

I think I could do it by taking a 'ones' array and multiplying every
row by a vector... but I'm not sure how to do it

```
a = (ones(100,100))*([])
```

??

Any tips?

Comment: You should also try meshgrid()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *repeat matrix* function (`repmat()`). You code would then look like this:

```
A = repmat( 1:100, 100, 1 );
```

This means that you're repeating the first argument of `repmat` 100 times vertically and once horizontally (i.e. you leave it as is horizontally).

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you. Both perfect answers. I'm giving the tick to the person who answered it first.

Answer (score 5):

You could multiply a column vector of 100 `1`s with a row vector of `1:100`.

```
ones(3,1)*(1:3)
ans =

   1   2   3 
   1   2   3
   1   2   3
```

Or you could use `repmat` ([edit] as Phonon wrote a few seconds before me [/edit]).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, repmat is the easy solution, and even arguably the right solution. But knowing how to visualize your aim and how to create something that yields that aim will give long term benefits in MATLAB. So try other solutions. For example...

```
cumsum(ones(100),2)

bsxfun(@plus,zeros(100,1),1:100)

ones(100,1)*(1:100)

cell2mat(repmat({1:100},100,1))
```

and the boring

```
repmat(1:100,100,1)
```